# Throw exception for default constructor java

Tags: java, class, oop, constructor

How do I prevent the default constructor from being used in Java?

In my assessment it says:

```
"We don't want the user to use the default constructor since the user has to specify the HashCode, and maximum load factor"
```

I thought this would do the trick, but apparently not (dictionary is a class that is used to throw exceptions):

```
public boolean HashDictionary() throws DictionaryException {}
```

DictionaryException Class:

```
public class DictionaryException extends Throwable {

}
```

Test to make sure it throws an exception when using default contructor(Supplied by lecturer):

```
try
{
    HashDictionary h = new HashDictionary();
    System.out.println("***Test 1 failed");

}
catch (DictionaryException e) {
        System.out.println("   Test 1 succeeded");
}
```

I just want to know how I could do this, as I'm not familiar with a method of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this:

```
 public DictionaryException(String error_string)
 {
     System.out.println(error_string);
 }
```

as the default constructor for DictionaryException

And then:

```
public HashDictionary() throws DictionaryException {
    throw new DictionaryException("Default constructor should not be used!");
}
```

This for the default constructor of the HashDictionary, the issue was that the type was a boolean, so I removed that and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare the default one as private if you do not want it to be called.

To answer your comment, you can throw an exception-

```
public HashDictionary() throws DictionaryException {
    throw new DictionaryException("Default constructor is not allowed.");
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer, as it will stop it at compile time.

Comment: The idea is that it runs and throws and error to show the lecturer that all tests were passed. As the first test is to see if the default constructor can be used, and if I can't get past this test then I can't do the other tests.

Comment: @ConnerStephenMcCabe You can throw an exception. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can

a) Omit the default constructor

b) Make the default constructor private

c) Throw an exception when the default constructor is used

```
public HashDictionary() throws DictionaryException {
    throw new DictionaryException("Default constructor should not be used!");
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best way, but it never compiles the code once the default constructor is set to private. I need it to compile, and just throw an exception if the default constructor is used with no arguments.

Comment: Then the default constructor MUST be present, but only to throw the exception. That means option C is the way to go

Comment: I tried this method, but it gives me an error by itself, it states that the exception is never thrown in the corresponding body of the try statment.

Comment: Oooh.. I see.. there was an error on my code, it is "public boolean" so it is not a constructor, but a method. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it like that. Just make the default constructor private:

```
private HashDictionary() {}
```

EDIT: What was the `boolean` doing in the Constructor definition? I just copied it...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it's funny you point that out since you answered with the same mistake ;-)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk My answer wasn't relevant to the constructor. It had more to do with `throws` declaration.

Comment: This method simply throws a compile error, the program needs to try it and throw an exception if it doesn't work.

Comment: @ConnerStephenMcCabe Why would anyone prefer a runtime to a compile time error?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to use the default constructor you can either omit the constructor if other non-default constructors are declared, or you can make the default constructor `private`.

The other issue you may be having is that the declaration you put in your question is not a constructor, it is a method. Constructors do not have return types.

Change this

```
public boolean HashDictionary() throws DictionaryException {}
```

to this

```
public HashDictionary() throws DictionaryException {}
```

better yet just change it to

```
private HashDictionary() {}
```

and then no one can access it outside of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. To Forbid the Default Constructor To Be Called from **Outside** the Class, use:

   private HashDictionary(){}
2. To Forbid the Default Constructor To Be Called from Even **Inside** the Class, use:

   Declare a **parameterized** constructor and don't write the **default non-parameterized** constructor inside the class. 
    public HashDictionary(String string){
    }
3. If you want some exception to be thrown while calling out the constructor, then:

   public HashDictionary() throws Exception {
       throw new Exception("throwing exception from constructor");
   }

Regards, Birendra.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a default constructor but you want to instantiate a class you need to implement a custom constructor. You have to tell the user what is needed to create a valid instance. And that's it! Default constructor won't be available anymore. If a constructor logic is too complicated, feel free to extract private methos, including a private constructor if you feal it's ok in your case. If you have many ways of creating instance you can use static factory-like methods and private ctor.
Making a private ctor only to disable the default one makes no sense (at least I don't see one).

If you don't want to instantiate a class (I mean you dont want to use the default ctor and you have no reason to create a custom ctor) this means you want to use only a static fields/methods, so make whole class static.

Oh, I assume that we're talking about non abstract classes.